# How can I compare two date string in array of Objects using NSPredicate?

Tags: arrays, object, swift4, nspredicate

I want to compare dates of each object using `NSPredicate`. If the Object has same dateCreated It will return an array of object which has same dates.

In the below Array of dictionary 0 index has the different date as compared to another one how can I get data like that.

Ex:

```
{
      "Data": [
    {
      "id": "c9967156ad8945fba8cc482cd8aad900",
      "description": "Hi",
      "dateCreated": "2018-03-20T06:15:11.000+0000",

    },
    {
      "id": "343e70818044457b884f7ad1907803fa",
      "description": "The only ",
      "dateCreated": "2018-03-16T17:22:50.000+0000",

    },
    {
      "id": "dd542edfaa364e40ae0ef0562b6831be",
      "description": "The new ",
      "dateCreated": "2018-03-16T17:10:36.000+0000",

    },
    {
      "id": "090f43c83e5b42039f70b133d031e715",
      "description": "The new version ",
      "dateCreated": "2018-03-16T17:08:07.000+0000",

    },
    {
      "id": "b2ddb8fa990843a28f0670d2b88e3d01",
      "description": "Add to the test",
      "dateCreated": "2018-03-16T17:08:07.000+0000",

    }
     ]
    }
```

**#Edit1**: 
I am converting dateCreated `String` object to `Date` and then I am using `NSPredicate` for desired data. Currently, I am trying with `NSPredicate`

**#Edit2**
Currently, I am not using NSPredicate. I am iterating each element of the array and compare its date

```
  if let dateCur = dateCreated.dateFromISO8601 {
     if let datePrev = dateCreatedPrev.dateFromISO8601 {
      let curLocal = ISO8601.getStringDate(dateCur).   // dd/MM/yyyy
      let prevLocal = ISO8601.getStringDate(datePrev). // dd/MM/yyyy
      if (curLocal.compare(prevLocal) != .orderedSame {
           //diffrent
      }else {
          //same
      }
     }
  }
```

I am using an extension for achieving it

```
extension Date {

func getFormatter() -> DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
    return formatter
}

var iso8601: String {
    return Formatter.iso8601.string(from: self)
}

extension String {
  var dateFromISO8601: Date? {
     return Formatter.iso8601.date(from: self)   // "Mar 22, 2017,    10:22 AM"
  }
}
```

Can you please help me.

Comment: `dateCreated` is a real `(NS)Date` object or a `(NS)String`? It seems to be a String according to your question title. Why is it a String? Do you absolutely need `NSPredicate` or a Swift filter is sufficient? It's unclear if you use a Date as a param to filter of if you want to know which is the most common date (or the last one) in the array and filter dates which aren't on the same day?

Comment: @Larme I am using NSDate or Date to convert dateCreated string object.

Comment: Each element will have the different `Date` here. Did you convert to only `dd:MM:yyyy`? Better if you show the conversion and if possible, what have you done with `NSPredicate`.

Comment: @nayem Okay wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no need to use `NSPredicate` in Swift (except the APIs which require `NSPredicate`).
The native `filter` method is more appropriate.

I recommend to decode the JSON

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "Data": [
        {"id": "c9967156ad8945fba8cc482cd8aad900", "description": "Hi", "dateCreated": "2018-03-20T06:15:11.000+0000"},
        {"id": "343e70818044457b884f7ad1907803fa", "description": "The only ", "dateCreated": "2018-03-16T17:22:50.000+0000"},
        {"id": "dd542edfaa364e40ae0ef0562b6831be", "description": "The new ", "dateCreated": "2018-03-16T17:10:36.000+0000"},
        {"id": "090f43c83e5b42039f70b133d031e715", "description": "The new version ", "dateCreated": "2018-03-16T17:08:07.000+0000"},
        {"id": "b2ddb8fa990843a28f0670d2b88e3d01", "description": "Add to the test", "dateCreated": "2018-03-16T17:08:07.000+0000"}
    ]
}
"""
```

into custom structs

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case items = "Data" }
    let items : [Item]
}

struct Item : Decodable {
    let id, description : String
    let dateCreated : Date
}
```

The decoder uses a custom date formatter to decode the ISO8601 date properly

```
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

do { 
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

The array is in `result.items`. Now you can `filter` the array by a specific date. In this example the reference date is created hard-coded with `DateComponents`.

```
    let components = DateComponents(timeZone: TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0), year:2018, month:03, day:16, hour:17, minute:8, second:7)
    let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
    let filteredItems = result.items.filter { $0.dateCreated == date }
    print(filteredItems)
} catch { print(error) }
```

If you want to find all matching records for a given date in the array use a loop

```
for item in result.items {
    let filteredItems = result.items.filter { $0.dateCreated == item.dateCreated }
    if filteredItems.count > 1 { print(filteredItems) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look into `Dictionary`'s initializer [`init(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init) which was introduced in **Swift 4**.

You should have your objects array. Then you can group them into `[String:Object]` where the `key` will be your `Date` in `yyyy-MM-dd` format as `String`.

> Prerequisites: Your `dateCreated` property should be in `Date` format.

```
let groupedObjectBySameDate = Dictionary(grouping: objects) { (object) -> String in
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter.string(from: object.dateCreated)
}
```

### An example:

As I don't know your data structure, I'm providing an easy example that can help you understand what's going on.

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return formatter
}
let stringDates = ["2018-03-20T06:15:11.000+0000", "2018-03-16T17:22:50.000+0000", "2018-03-16T17:10:36.000+0000", "2018-03-16T17:08:07.000+0000", "2018-03-16T17:08:07.000+0000"]
let dates = stringDates.map { (each) -> Date in
    return dateFormatter.date(from: each) ?? Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
}

let groupedObjectBySameDate = Dictionary(grouping: dates) { (date) -> String in
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
print(groupedObjectBySameDate)

// This will produce:
// [
//     "2018-03-20": [2018-03-20 06:15:11 +0000], 
//     "2018-03-16": [2018-03-16 17:22:50 +0000, 2018-03-16 17:10:36 +0000, 2018-03-16 17:08:07 +0000, 2018-03-16 17:08:07 +0000]
// ]
```